# VS-Code, Django, runserver plus "Couldn't spawn debuggee: embedded null byte"

Tags: django

If i run

```
./manage.py runserver_plus --key-file selftest-key --cert-file selftest-cert --nopin localhost:8443
```

everthing works fine. My `launch.json` looks like:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver_plus",
            "--key-file",
            "selftest-key",
            "--cert-file",
            "selftest-cert",
            "--nopin",
            "localhost:8443",
        ],
        "django": true,
        "justMyCode": false
    }
]
}
```

What should actually do the exact same thing like running the command in the shell.

But if I want to run the Server over VS-Codes "Run And Debug" function, I get following error:

[image]

Before I checkedout the project again, everything worked fine. I really don't understand what VS-Code wants from me, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is that old in the meanwhile but I want to share my solution with you if someone ever runs into this weired, annoying bug. For what reason ever VS-Codes [Global launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) got messed up (I never touched this file). In my case deleting the Global launch configuration settings file fixed it. I just came behind that because the debugger stopped working in all projects. This made it obvious that it couldn't have been a local setting and that led me to the solution. For the sake of peace, please don't just delete any files if you don't know whether it will have further effects on your system, or make a backup copy beforehand so that you can restore the original state in case something else breaks.